# Colocar imagem num menu bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Como eu coloco uma imagem no canto direito de uma barra de menu com bootstrap. Abaixo o código de minha Layout(Master)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Util.js")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Pedidos", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Fiz isso, mas a imagem ficou à esquerda e não à direita.

```
..........
<div class="container">
            <a class="brand"><img src="~/Images/ache.jpg" /></a>
                <div class="navbar-header">
.............
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Mova a image acima do navbar-header e associe a classes navbar-right.
>
> Isto coloca sua imagem do lado direito na visualização em desktops, e
>   vai para a esquerda em dispositivos móveis, pois o botão do menu deve
>   ser o elemento mais à direita.
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/KHtU4/embedded/result/
>
> ```
> <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
>   <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">CesaStack</a>
>   <div class="navbar-header">
>       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
>           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
>           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>       </button>          
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
>       <!-- snip -->
>   </div>
> </nav>
> ```

Fonte: [Esta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22508573/)

Answer (score 1):

Assim:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand pull-right"><img src="~/Images/ache.jpg" /></a>
...
```

Comment: Ambas as respostas deram certo. Vou marcar uma, mas considero ambos correto.